# Term for Patterns Within A Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For instance, the permutations of the set {1,2} taking 2 elements would be:

- {1,2}
- {2,1}

and with repitition

- {1,1}
- {2,2}

I'm wondering if there is a term to describe the concept of patterns within these permutations such as:

- {1, }
- { ,1}
- {2, }
- { ,2}

Comment: If the indices you select have to be consecutive, the term is [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring). Otherwise, it is [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).

Comment: As far as I can tell subsequence and substring do not account for arrangements consisting of non-contiguous elements such as {1, ,3} where the space is sort of a wildcard.

Comment: Subsequence does allow for non-contiguous elements. However, in the sequence {1,2,4,2,3}, the subsequences {1,2, , ,3} and {1, , ,2,3} are considered the same, which may or not be what you want.

Comment: I see. I'm wondering if there is a term for the concept where those subsequences are considered different.

Comment: Like do you want to take each element in a set separately? like {1},{2} and so on?? I don't understand what you mean with {1,} or {,1}

Comment: I'm wondering if their is a concept within combinatorics for permutations/subsequences of a set that preserves spacing.